# get/receive/store data from https link, sent from payment site

Tags: api, post, curl, payment

I posted user details and card details to my payment service provider using their API and after a successful payment they redirect to my website, which i posted them.

now the redirection link i have is this way:-
http://mywebsite.sa/pay_completed.php?transaction=284&order_id=

All i need is to store that above transaction and order_id value into my variables,so can update my db.
By searching i have found i can do this by using cURL and I tried, not sure how to do so?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using

```
    print_r($_REQUEST)
```

I can get all the posted values from URL above